# JSON.NET JsonConvert vs .NET JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: .net, json, json.net

What is better to use when it comes to encoding and decoding of JSON in .NET? I have tried both and upto this point JsonConvert seems to be doing a good job. I have used JavaScriptSerializer in the past successfully but have had some problems in the recent past with it. Is it better to use JSON.NET than the .NET class?

What are the preferred functions for encoding/decoding json using the appropriate library? I use SerializeObject/DeSerializeObject from JSON.NET and Serialize/DeSerialize from .NET.

Thanks

Comment: There is [good comparison here](http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=344) in terms of speed. Even after reading this article I've used Newtonsoft.Json, as it did decent job for me.

Comment: The Newtonsoft website provides a table of feature comparison and some benchmarks worth having a look at too: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonNetVsDotNetSerializers.htm

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I think [this](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) is exactly the kind of comparison you are looking for.

It basically says that JSON.Net is better because it among other things...

- Is **faster**
- Has **LINQ** to JSON support
- Can **convert** JSON to and from **XML**

In my opinion the only positive, (and it is a small positive), I can see for the built-in serializer is that there is no extra external dependency to manage.

**Edit**: Codeplex is shutting down one day so you can find the comparison [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) as well, just search for "Feature comparison" on the page.

Comment: _Is faster_  Did you test it? I tried with .NET 4.5.2 and Json.NET 9.01 and it's not at all faster than the JavaScriptSerializer. The speed stats in the official site are referring to JSON.NET 5...a little outdated!

Comment: @krlzlx .Net 4.5.2 was released in May 2015, and JSON.Net 9.01 a few months ago while I wrote this answer 3 years ago in 2013. Why don't you provide an updated answer with your metrics instead of being snarky!

Comment: I'm sorry I know your answer is from 2013. But you didn't provide any metrics either except from the ones in the Json.NET website. I was disappointed when I tested it. That's all.

Answer (score 28):

For a very long time, my app used `JavascriptSerializer` and saw no real reason to migrate. Even if performance comparisons claim huge percentage gains, we're talking milliseconds.

But here's one very very good reason to migrate: `JavascriptSerializer` isn't available in `.Net Core` because it's part of `System.Web` So if you're using `JavascriptSerializer`, you're stuck and have to migrate to JSON.net

Comment: asp net core uses json.net by default.

Comment: .Net core now has the [System.Text.Json serialisers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to) so this is no longer correct. [MS now want you to use this serialiser not the Newtonsoft one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to). Though to echo your point (above) I haven't seen a need to move TBH