# Can't populate list with deserialized JSON in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, deserialization

I am writing an app with ASP.NET MVC 4 and I try to populate list inside object of my type. I wrote console app just to try this code out:

```
 using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            var json = webClient.DownloadString(URL);
            var myTypeVariable= new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<MyTypeSummary>(json);
            return myTypeVariable;
        }
```

myTypeVariable is an object of type:

```
public class MyTypeSummary
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<MyType> MyTypeItems{ get; set; }
    public DateTime PublicationDate { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunatelly when I used this code in ASP.NET Index() action it got only DateTime property populated properly. The MyTypeItems Listremained null, just opposite to the effect of executing this in my console application(List was properly populated).

My class looks like this:

```
public class MyType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int Unit { get; set; }
    public double Price1{ get; set; }
    public double Price2{ get; set; }
    public double Price3{ get; set; }
}
```

And I can't figure out why in console app this worked well and in asp isn't working at all. Can anyone help?
Edit: this is the json string I am getting:

```
"{\"publicationDate\":\"2016-09-23T11:36:26.4723947Z\",\"items\":[{\"name\":\"US Dollar\",\"code\":\"USD\",\"unit\":1,\"purchasePrice\":3.6682,\"sellPrice\":3.6779,\"averagePrice\":3.6730},{\"name\":\"Euro\",\"code\":\"EUR\",\"unit\":1,\"purchasePrice\":3.8842,\"sellPrice\":3.9027,\"averagePrice\":3.8935},{\"name\":\"Swiss Franc\",\"code\":\"CHF\",\"unit\":1,\"purchasePrice\":3.7940,\"sellPrice\":3.8041,\"averagePrice\":3.7990},{\"name\":\"Russian ruble\",\"code\":\"RUB\",\"unit\":100,\"purchasePrice\":6.8865,\"sellPrice\":6.9096,\"averagePrice\":6.8981},{\"name\":\"Czech koruna\",\"code\":\"CZK\",\"unit\":100,\"purchasePrice\":13.9250,\"sellPrice\":13.9584,\"averagePrice\":13.9417},{\"name\":\"Pound sterling\",\"code\":\"GBP\",\"unit\":1,\"purchasePrice\":5.6786,\"sellPrice\":5.6989,\"averagePrice\":5.6887}]}"
```

Comment: `.Deserialize<MyTypeSummary>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke excuse me for my mistake in post, in fact I was deserializing MyTypeSummary instead of MyType as I wrote firstly. Any other thoughts?

Comment: There's nothing special about ASP.NET. Are you sure the json string is OK? Please post the input

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos posted. Can I leave it like it is or make it somehow more readable?

Comment: Try to replace `public List<MyType> MyTypeItems` with `public List<MyType> items`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class should be like this as per the JSON you provided. You can try converting your JSON to object at [Json2Csharp](http://json2csharp.com/).

```
 public class Item
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
        public int unit { get; set; }
        public double purchasePrice { get; set; }
        public double sellPrice { get; set; }
        public double averagePrice { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyTypeSummary
    {
        public string publicationDate { get; set; }
        public List<Item> items { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: it was the items. Inconsistence in naming. Thank You @AliasgarRajpiplawala !

Answer (score 1):

`.Deserialize<MyTypeSummary>` as @stephen-muecke said.

Personally I use the NuGet package manager to install `NewtonSoft.Json' and then use:

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyTypeSummary>(json);` [found here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm)

[Here is why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263166/json-net-jsonconvert-vs-net-javascriptserializer)

Comment: I used JsonConvert and still cant populate my list. There are no differences in code in my console app and in asp.net

Comment: @VeryVicious post the string. There's nothing special about ASP.NET and JSON. Without the input string it's impossible to help. Make sure you add logging code to your ASP.NET application and post the actual string returned, not the one you tried in your console