# What happens after ActionResult returned?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Using MVC 5 I return Json. The total time is 40 milliseconds to get to the point where the data is returned.

However it takes `6000 millisconds` for the browser to get the data, even running it on the server.

My question is what happens after I return the value. I am trying to find out what causes the slowness.

```
    public JsonResult Read(....)
    {
        var all = _userManager.GetStuff();
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var r= Json(all .....);
        Trace.WriteLine("READ" + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        watch.Stop();

        return r;  //Takes 40 milliseconds to get here
    }
```

Comment: How many items are in all, is the stuff object is simple object, or complex ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the internal code for the `JsonResult` type.

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{
  if (context == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
  if (this.JsonRequestBehavior == JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet && string.Equals(context.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    throw new InvalidOperationException(MvcResources.JsonRequest_GetNotAllowed);
  HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;
  response.ContentType = string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ContentType) ? "application/json" : this.ContentType;
  if (this.ContentEncoding != null)
    response.ContentEncoding = this.ContentEncoding;
  if (this.Data == null)
    return;
  JavaScriptSerializer scriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  if (this.MaxJsonLength.HasValue)
    scriptSerializer.MaxJsonLength = this.MaxJsonLength.Value;
  if (this.RecursionLimit.HasValue)
    scriptSerializer.RecursionLimit = this.RecursionLimit.Value;
  response.Write(scriptSerializer.Serialize(this.Data));
}
```

From the point of view the internal code, the `JavaScriptSerializer` is the type used to serialize the object you pass to the `JsonResult`. You could check if this is the step where your code is taking slow process.

Try to make your controller like this:

```
public JsonResult Read(....)
{
    var all = _userManager.GetStuff();
    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    var scriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = scriptSerializer.Serialize(all);

    Trace.WriteLine("READ" + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    watch.Stop();

    return json;  //Takes 40 milliseconds to get here
}
```

If the problem persists, you could implement an alternative, you could implement your own JsonResult using the [`JSON.Net`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) library, which can provide [better results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18314625/316799). For Sample, add the namespace:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

The controller:

```
public JsonResult Read(....)
{
    var all = _userManager.GetStuff();
    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(all);

    Trace.WriteLine("READ" + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    watch.Stop();

    return Content(json, "application/json");  //Takes 40 milliseconds to get here
}
```

And finally, you could compare the performance. Another possible way is to use another format which can speed up the serialization such as xml or binary.