# retrive specific data from nested json string

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

I have a block of JSON as follows:

```
{
    "FirstName": "JON",
    "LastName": "BAYN",
    "Data": [
        {
            "Plan": "DAY"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have built it using JavaScriptSerializer like

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer_user = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                            dynamic jsonObject = serializer_user.Deserialize<dynamic>(content_);

dynamic firstname = jsonObject["FirstName"];
firstname = jsonObject["FirstName"];
```

But I am not able to read from nested "Details" >> "Plan". I've been unable to piece together how to accomplish this goal.

Comment: _"But I am not able to read from nested Details >> Plan"_ - do you try it? Show us.

Comment: Can you retrieve the `FirstName` and `LastName`? Did you create a class for Deserialization?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserializing JSON data to C# using JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546138/deserializing-json-data-to-c-sharp-using-json-net)

Comment: @NatPongjardenlarp it is not a duplicate because it is about `JavaScriptSerializer` and not `JSON.Net`

Comment: Hazz_Rush - Can you retrieve the FirstName and LastName? -- yes with this dynamic firstname = jsonObject["FirstName"];
firstname = jsonObject["FirstName"];

Answer (score 2):

At first, make model class to your json schema:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public int MemberID { get; set; }
    public Detail[] Details { get; set; }
}

public class Detail
{
    public string Plan { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProductStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProductEndDate { get; set; }
    public string Flag { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can deserialize your json string to RootObject (Use [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) instead of `JavaScriptSerializer` because it is [faster etc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18314625/5789864)):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
..
// If Json.NET is not option:
// var obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Rootobject>(json)
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```

And now you are able to access object structure like following:

```
if (obj.Details != null)
{
    foreach (var detail in obj.Details)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(detail.Plan);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, this will actually solve the problem, but what if OP can't switch from `JavaScriptSerializer` to `JSON.net`? Can you add a solution for that case?

Comment: Risto M - Perfect!! if "Details" array more than 1 or none.. in that case getting error as index was outside the bounds of the json array

Comment: @Vivan_J Yep, that `obj.Details[0]` was just an example. You have check array bounds before accessing Details-array

Comment: @RistoM  obj.Details[0].plan.Length > 1 && obj.Details[0].plan != null not working if it none..

Comment: I updated answer to be more resilient (rememer to check answer accepted if working :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create new classes for it and deserialize it, you could just do a regex.